# How do jQuery plugins maintain global state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have recently written my first simple jQuery plugin. Proud I am.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnhoffman/wSeLY/1/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.makeRed = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css("color", "#f00");
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I am wondering why it works though. I pass the jQuery object into this enclosed function that runs immediately.

Subsequently, isn't the |$| object a local variable within that anonymous function? How does it change the global singleton jQuery object?

In other words, aren't I just adding a function via `$.fn.myFunctionName` to the object |$| local to the enclosed function? How does it change the global jQuery object and make my function (`makeRed`) available to selectors all over the global scope of my script?

Comment: Read up on how closures work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> isn't the |$| object a local variable within that anonymous function?

Yes, `$` is a local variable in the function but, and this is a big but, it is a reference to the `jQuery` object that is globally accessible. Things look like this:

```
window.jQuery (global) ----->-----> { ... }
                                    ^
                                    |
$ (local) ------------------>-------+
```

So, you have two variables that point at the same object and that object still exists after your anonymous function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in Javascript are passed by reference, therefore any updates within your function are maintained on the jQuery object. You are just referring to it by the name `$`.

I highly recommend you read: [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742) it explains all this.